# Finding if a string already exists inside an array of strings -javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array called blog.likes and i want to check to see if the id of the current logged in user(req.user._id) already exists inside the array of likes. If it does then delete the id from the array if it doesn't then add the user id inside the array. With the code i have now if i press the like button once it likes the post if i press it again it removes the like but if a post has a like and i log in with a different user and press the like button many times it starts to delete all the likes not only the likes that are made by one user.

```
         if (blog.likes.indexOf(req.user._id) > -1 ){
             blog.likes.shift(req.user._id);
             blog.save();
           } else {
          blog.likes.push(req.user);
           blog.save();
          }
```

Comment: The shift array method does not look for the array element with value equal to a parameter and remove it.  It removes the first element from the array.  So you are removing the first element from the array which is not the correct element, and next time your user id is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [shift](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp) function will only remove the first element from the array, paying no heed to the logged in user id. Use [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) function to achieve the desired result.
Change your code to this:

```
let userIndex = blog.likes.indexOf(req.user._id);
if (userIndex > -1) {
  blog.likes.splice(userIndex, 1);
} else {
  blog.likes.push(req.user);
}
blog.save();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments .shift() is not the correct method to use.  Give this a try:

```
var f = blog.likes.indexOf(req.user._id);
if (f > -1 ) {
  blog.likes.splice(f, 1);
} else {
  blog.likes.push(req.user);
}
blog.save();
```